# Twowayview automatically add padding when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using [Twowayview](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) in one of my projects. Which is an extension of androids [Recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) library. (Having features like vertical horizontal staggered, spannable grid and listviews).Sometimes the items in the gridview disappears when scrolling (ie, It automatically adding padding each time it scrolls and atlast all items scroll to the side we scrolled). It was a random behavior not experiencing every time.

Watch this video, [Recyclerview scroll issue](https://vid.me/ntVs)

Please find additional reference about this issue on this link below,

[Padding problem #140](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/issues/140)

This auto padding issue mostly occur when we add or remove  the adapter with new items.

Please find the widget i have used below with the attributes

```
<org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
android:id="@+id/spannable_grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animationCache="false"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
android:scrollbarSize="0px"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:scrollingCache="false"
app:layoutManager="SpannableGridLayoutManager"
app:numColumn="6"
app:numRow="6" />
```

I found some solutions like remove the padding from Twowayview, CliptoPadding , etc. But none of these working for me. I am using Recyclerview version 21.0.0. Anybody experiencing this issue ?. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: I Found solution for this issue, Ref _ ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137920/twoway-view-add-empty-space-automatically-solved

Answer (score 5):

I'm reposting the answer by [Ish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1881611/ish)

First of all keep you must use code of TwoWay-View library not jar.

1. Open layout folder of library.
2. Browse the package org.lucasr.twowayview.widget
3. Open BaseLayoutManager class
4. Jump to Line no. 362
5. You will found code as

if (anchorItemPosition > 0 && (refreshingLanes || !restoringLanes))
  {

replace this line by this one

if (anchorItemPosition > 0 && refreshingLanes && !restoringLanes) {
Above change in BaseLayoutManager class work for me as a solution to above mentioned issues.

Hope this will help you all TwoWay-View users.

Comment: This change is merged in a fork of the original project. Check out the fork by [mrolcsi](https://github.com/mrolcsi/twoway-view) or his [commit](https://github.com/mrolcsi/twoway-view/commit/8cc9dfa1e3beed37cf9f90cde802b4d2e3ad9eb2). Using this fork instead of the original, you can compile and get a jar with the fix instead of managing all the source code in your own project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a custom onScrollListener to correct it when its State().getTargetScrollPosition() is perhaps outside the expected range?

Comment: This can't be answer. Add comment to the question.

Comment: Don't have enough rep to do that.